# Can't write to S3 when using AWS Batch Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-batch

I'm trying to run a very simple script that writes to S3 from an AWS batch job.

When I run the container locally on my machine, I can write to the S3 bucket (the credentials are stored in the container...which I know is not advised, but in this case is simply to test). However, when I start a batch job with this same container, I cannot seem to write to s3.

The batch job will succeed, but the S3 bucket doesn't show the file that should have been written.

The command I give the batch job is below

```
python3 -c \
'import boto3; s3=boto3.resource("s3"); f=open("test.txt", "w");
f.write("works"); f.close(); 
s3.Object(<bucket>, "test.txt").upload_file("test.txt")'
```

Comment: How are thy stored in the container? What error do you get?

Comment: I add the file when I built the container and pushed this container build to ECR. I don't get an error, which is what's confusing. It says the job succeeded with the command given.

Comment: Are you sure the code even runs?

Comment: I replaced the command with a command I figured would create an error (misspelled python interpreter name) and failed as expected, so I assumed it was executing. Any suggestions on how to check this? I'm quite unfamiliar with AWS, as you may tell

Comment: @kichik your intuition was right. Seems the code is not running. I purposefully removed the `boto3` import, which should make this fail, but it does not, which seems to indicate the code doesn't actually run. I thought the command would just be handed over to `docker run`.